# How to fix Missing ${ from the text: error - Apache Camel 2.12 to 2.16.4 uprade

Tags: apache-camel

We are upgrading from Apache Camel 2.12 to 2.16.4 and running into issues with one of the routes.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing ${ from the text: file:C:\OnDemandOutput?fileName=RPFPos_L2W.$simple{in.header.accountNum}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.csv
```

```xml
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <propertyPlaceholder id="ignoreId" location="classpath:reformMB.properties"
                               prefixToken="${" suffixToken="}"/>

    <route id="sendNotification">
        <from uri="jms:queue:queue.sendNotification"/>
        <to uri="file:${OnDemand.output.url}?fileName=RPFPos_L2W.$simple{in.header.accountNum}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.csv"/> 
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

As per documentation this should have worked. Can someone help me in understanding what is wrong ?

According to the [official documentation](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/modules/ROOT/pages/using-propertyplaceholder.adoc) one should be able to refer to Camel's properties using `$simple{...}` like this:

> #### Clashing Spring Property Placeholders with Camels Simple Language
>
> Take notice when using Spring bridging placeholder then the spring ${} syntax clashes with the Simple in Camel, and therefore take care.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <setHeader headerName="Exchange.FILE_NAME">
>   <simple>{{file.rootdir}}/${in.header.CamelFileName}</simple> 
> </setHeader>
> ```
>
> clashes with Spring property placeholders, and you should use `$simple{}` to indicate using the Simple language in Camel.
>
> ```
> <setHeader headerName="Exchange.FILE_NAME">
>     <simple>{{file.rootdir}}/$simple{in.header.CamelFileName}</simple
> </setHeader>
> ```

Comment: Maybe you can try [dynamic to](http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html) (toD) or Recipient List [recipientList](https://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html)

Comment: [The file-language documentation](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-base/src/main/docs/file-language.adoc#using-spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-together-with-the-file-component) contains a sample on how you might achieve what you attempt if `toD(...)` does not solve your problem

Comment: toD() gives me the same results. 2.16.4 version of camel is not able to parse $simple{}, when you have prefixToken="${" suffixToken="}" in the propertyPlaceholder. I am getting the same result with camel 2.24.1 as well.